# With a href="#" JQuery work but with a href="page.jsp" not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsp

Already I have asked this question few days back not got any satisfactory reply My problem is when I click on menu it must be highlighted as selected. But this is not happening, when I am selecting any menu tab which is link with page then Home tab shown as selected, but if I replace that page link with # then that tab is showing as selected. Below is the code give for gallery.jsp,guestHead.jsp and CSS
gallery.jsp

```
<table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr bgcolor="#36b0b6">
    <td width="100%"><% if(session.getAttribute("userid")=="Admin"){ %>
        <jsp:include page="adminHead.jsp"></jsp:include></td>
        <% } else { %>
        <jsp:include page="guestHead.jsp"></jsp:include></td>
        <% } %></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" bgcolor="#36b0b6">
  <tr bgcolor="#36b0b6">
    <td width="10%" height="557" valign="top">
     <jsp:include page="left.jsp"></jsp:include>
    </td>
    <td width="75%" valign="top">       
    <div class="container">
            <div class="image-row">
                <div class="image-set">
                    <a class="example-image-link" href="img/demopage/image-3.jpg" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="Click the right half of the image to move forward."><img class="example-image" src="img/demopage/thumb-3.jpg" alt=""/></a>
                    <a class="example-image-link" href="img/demopage/image-4.jpg" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="Or press the right arrow on your keyboard."><img class="example-image" src="img/demopage/thumb-4.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                    <a class="example-image-link" href="img/demopage/image-5.jpg" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="The next image in the set is preloaded as you're viewing."><img class="example-image" src="img/demopage/thumb-5.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                    <a class="example-image-link" href="img/demopage/image-6.jpg" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="Click anywhere outside the image or the X to the right to close."><img class="example-image" src="img/demopage/thumb-6.jpg" alt="" /></a>
        </div>
            </div>
    </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<table>
```

guestHead.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
<script src="jquery-1.12.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script language="javascript">
$(window).load(function(){
  $('#cssmenu li').on('click', function(){
    $('li.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });
});
</script>

<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul> 
  <li class='active'><a href="index.jsp">Home</a></li> 
  <li><a href="Untitled-1.jsp">About Us</a></li> 
  <li><a href="gallery.jsp">Gallery</a></li> 
  <li><a href="#">Alumni</a></li> 
  <li><a href="#">Events</a></li> 
  <li><a href="#">Polling</a></li> 
  <li><a href="#">Feedback</a></li> 
  <li class='last'><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li> 
</ul>   
</div>
```

style.css

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700);
@charset "UTF-8";
/* Base Styles */
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu li,
#cssmenu a {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  line-height: 1;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
#cssmenu {
  border: 1px solid #133e40;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -ms-border-radius: 5px;
  -o-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: auto;
}
#cssmenu ul {
  zoom: 1;
  background: #36b0b6;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #36b0b6 0%, #2a8a8f 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #36b0b6), color-stop(100%, #2a8a8f));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #36b0b6 0%, #2a8a8f 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #36b0b6 0%, #2a8a8f 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #36b0b6 0%, #2a8a8f 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(top, #36b0b6 0%, #2a8a8f 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='@top-color', endColorstr='@bottom-color', GradientType=0);
  padding: 5px 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -ms-border-radius: 5px;
  -o-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
#cssmenu ul:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
}
#cssmenu ul:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
#cssmenu li {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 5px 0 0;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}
#cssmenu li a {
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -ms-border-radius: 5px;
  -o-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 15px 9px 15px;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  font-size: 16px;
}
#cssmenu li.active {
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -ms-border-radius: 5px;
  -o-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #36b0b6;
}
#cssmenu li.active a {
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -ms-border-radius: 5px;
  -o-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: block;
  background: #1e6468;
  border: 1px solid #133e40;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 5px 10px #133e40;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 5px 10px #133e40;
  box-shadow: inset 0 5px 10px #133e40;
}
#cssmenu li:hover {
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -ms-border-radius: 5px;
  -o-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #36b0b6;
}
#cssmenu li:hover a {
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -ms-border-radius: 5px;
  -o-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: block;
  background: #1e6468;
  border: 1px solid #133e40;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 5px 10px #133e40;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 5px 10px #133e40;
  box-shadow: inset 0 5px 10px #133e40;
}
```

[image showing the gallery tab clicked but home is selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxqGX.jpg)

[image showing Alumni tab clicked and Alumni is selected which is "#"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBgFD.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

In the one case:

1. You modify the classes an element belongs to in the *current page*
2. You follow the link to `#`, which is the top of the *current page*

In the other case:

1. You modify the classes an element belongs to in the *current page*
2. You follow the link to `page.jsp`, which is a *different* page, which doesn't have the modifications you just made to the DOM (of the last page) in it

---

Use server side code to set the class when the page is requested.

Comment: Sir I am learning Jquery, I am not expert like you, I can't understand what you want to say, kindly tell me what I need to do for making this menu working. I will be obliged.

Comment: Use server side code to set the class when the page is requested. (Which has nothing to do with jQuery. jQuery is the wrong tool for the job.)

Comment: Since you are already using JSP, it would be the logical choice for the rest of your server side code.

Comment: Sir can you do a favor, kindly show me some code hint on this